# WPF Rich Text Box doesn't accept \sl rtf tag

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a WPF (vb.net) application with a RichTextBox and load a rtf file into it. This works basically as expected except with the line spacing tag \sl
For me it looks like the RichTextBox does not handle this tag correctly - am I right with this assumption? The same file shows the correct line spacing in MS Wordpad.

Has anyone of you had the same problem - and found a solution?
Thanks for each hint?

This is the code I use to load the rtf into the box

```
Dim tr As TextRange = New TextRange(TextBoxMain.Document.ContentStart, TextBoxMain.Document.ContentEnd)

tr.Load(myFileStream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf)
```

Alois

Comment: Where are you getting \sl is a line feed?  I am used to \r\n.

Comment: no, its not a line feed, its a line-space - the space between two lines. The \sl is followed by a number like this: \sl350 which is 1.5 lines

Comment: @Blam He's not referring to a C# string escape code, he's referring to an RTF tag.  @alois, I do not know whether it is supported, but it is entirely possible that the tag was introduced in a newer version of the RTF specification than `RichTetBox` supports.

Comment: the tag is already in version 1.5 of the rtf specification, which is from 1997